# Working with Date and LocalDate

Tags: kotlin

I want to use an array of `data class` where one of the parameters is `Date`, I could not use [Date()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/-date/index.html) as it looks to be related to `KotlinJS`, so I tried using `LocalDate` so I wrote the below code:

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.util.*

data class transaction (var date: LocalDate, var quantity: Double)
val formatter: DateTimeFormatter
    get() = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.mm.yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var salesOrders = ArrayList<transaction>()

    println("Hello, world! ")

    salesOrders.set(0, transaction(LocalDate.parse("01.02.2018", formatter), 0.0))


    println(salesOrders)

}
```

But, as shown at [tryKotlin](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/71gmdrahfvj03mgcf59chfs0nq/5n5qtiv8o4u3b2eq0lt5kn6qi7) I'm getting an error, that:

> Text '01.02.2018' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {Year=2018, MinuteOfHour=2, DayOfMonth=1}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the [DateTimeFormatter documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), the "m" character in the pattern means "minute"; "month" is "M". You need to change "mm" to "MM".

Comment: Thanks, I got another error for the same line after changing the `mm` to `MM`, which is: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:444)
    at Simplest_versionKt.main(Simplest version.kt:19)`

Comment: This happens because `salesOrders` is an empty list. Use the `add()` method to add a value to a list.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to use `Date` instead of `LocalDate`

Comment: You can use the [java.util.Date class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) in Kotlin, but `LocalDate` is the more modern API, so you should use it.

Comment: Thanks, last Question, any idea how to get the week number? can you update your answer to include this.

Comment: You can find an answer to this question in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

Answer (score 0):

it must be `MM` not `mm` see [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: Thanks, I got another error for the same line after changing the `mm` to `MM`, which is: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:444)
    at Simplest_versionKt.main(Simplest version.kt:19)`

Comment: you have to use add() instead of set()

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to use `Date` instead of `LocalDate`